# Drools rules import with wildcard

Tags: import, wildcard, drools, rules

I am working with Drools rules. Some developers have created rules which I have to put on Guvnor (rules repository) and build packages. In these rules they have import statements with wildcards, for example: import org.drools.runtime.rule.*;

When I upload this on Guvnor and try to build, it tells me: 
Unable to introspect model for wild card imports (org.drools.runtime.rule.*). Please explicitly import each fact type you require.

Is it possible to use wildcard imports in Drools rules???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in Drools DRL, but not in Guvnor.

Guvnor adds automatically all the imports when you upload your model jar.

You can find more information about this here https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/BRMS-257

Comment: Actually it was my mistake. It is impossible to validate imports with wildcards on Guvnor, but the packages can be built even with wildcards.